# React.JS TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

Having an issue with a react form and I can't figure it out. I am getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined` when submitting. The issue started when I added "location" to the form. Not sure how this is causing it to break as I am just adding another item to the form. I have attempted to fix any typos, and when I take out the "location" it submits with no issue.

```
import React from "react";
import Firebase from "firebase";
import config from "./config";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    Firebase.initializeApp(config);

    this.state = {
      pallets: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getUserData();
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevState !== this.state) {
      this.writeUserData();
    }
  }

  writeUserData = () => {
    Firebase.database()
      .ref("/")
      .set(this.state);
    console.log("DATA SAVED");
  };

  getUserData = () => {
    let ref = Firebase.database().ref("/");
    ref.on("value", snapshot => {
      const state = snapshot.val();
      this.setState(state);
    });
  };

  handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    let name = this.refs.name.value;
    let QTY = this.refs.QTY.value;
    let uid = this.refs.uid.value;
    let location = this.refs.location.value;




    if (uid && name && QTY && location) {
      const { pallets } = this.state;
      const devIndex = pallets.findIndex(data => {
        return data.uid === uid;
      });
      pallets[devIndex].name = name;
      pallets[devIndex].QTY = QTY;
      pallets[devIndex].location = location;
      this.setState({ pallets });
    } else if (name && QTY && location) {
      const uid = new Date().getTime().toString();
      const { pallets } = this.state;
      pallets.push({ uid, name, QTY, location });
      this.setState({ pallets });
    }

    this.refs.name.value = "";
    this.refs.QTY.value = "";
    this.refs.uid.value = "";
    this.refs.location.value = "";
  };

  removeData = pallet => {
    const { pallets } = this.state;
    const newState = pallets.filter(data => {
      return data.uid !== pallet.uid;
    });
    this.setState({ pallets: newState });
  };

  updateData = pallet => {
    this.refs.uid.value = pallet.uid;
    this.refs.name.value = pallet.name;
    this.refs.QTY.value = pallet.QTY;
    this.refs.location.value =pallet.location;
  };

  render() {
    const { pallets } = this.state;
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-xl-12">
              <h1>Creating Pallet App</h1>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-xl-12">
              {pallets.map(pallet => (
                <div
                  key={pallet.uid}
                  className="card float-left"
                  style={{ width: "18rem", marginRight: "1rem" }}
                >
                  <div className="card-body">
                    <h5 className="card-title">{pallet.name}</h5>
                    <p className="card-text">{pallet.QTY}</p>
                    <p className="card-text">{pallet.location}</p>

                    <button
                      onClick={() => this.removeData(pallet)}
                      className="btn btn-link"
                    >
                      Delete
                    </button>
                    <button
                      onClick={() => this.updateData(pallet)}
                      className="btn btn-link"
                    >
                      Edit
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-xl-12">
              <h1>Add new pallet here</h1>
              <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <div className="form-row">
                  <input type="hidden" ref="uid" />
                  <div className="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label>Name</label>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      ref="name"
                      className="form-control"
                      placeholder="Name"
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div className="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label>QTY</label>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      ref="QTY"
                      className="form-control"
                      placeholder="QTY"
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div className="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label>Location</label>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      ref="QTY"
                      className="form-control"
                      placeholder="Location"
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
                  Save
                </button>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Can you post the exact error you are getting along with the line the error message is referencing?

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
App._this.handleSubmit
C:/Users/Web Content/Desktop/react-firebase-real-time-database-basic/src/App.js:45
  42 | let name = this.refs.name.value;
  43 | let QTY = this.refs.QTY.value;
  44 | let uid = this.refs.uid.value;
> 45 | let location = this.refs.location.value;
     | ^

Comment: Sorry can't figure out the formatting it looks like the issue is being caused by line 45

Comment: The ref of Location input is QTY,maybe that cause the issue?

Comment: @HagaiHarari I just tried that no go, but thanks anyway!

Comment: Your `this.refs` looks like it's causing the issue, because `.value` of all three of those is returning as undefined. You're referencing `this.refs` multiple times in the code above though, so it's hard to pinpoint where 43,44,45 is without your code editor in front of me. Edit your code to show the line where your error is occuring.

Comment: Sorry about that line 45 is `let location = this.refs.location.value;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't created a ref named `location`

Change:

```
<input
  type="text"
  ref="QTY"
  className="form-control"
  placeholder="Location"
/>
```

to:

```
<input
  type="text"
  ref="location"
  className="form-control"
  placeholder="Location"
/>
```

Comment: I had tried that before but it looks like it was a typo on my part! Thank you so much!